# Darboux theorem and its validation at boundary points of closed interval

Tags: calculus

Darboux principle says, "Let I be a closed interval, f : I ----> R a real-valued differentiable function. Then f ' has the intermediate value property: If a and b are points in I with a < b , then for every y between f '(a ) and f '(b) , there exists an x in (a,b) such that f'( x )= y."
I have confusion at following points
a) f is differentiable means if I =[A,B] then f is differentiable at boundary points A,B also?
b) what happens when we replace closed interval, I =[a,b]  to open interval, I=(a,b)? Still we can apply darboux principle? Or in that condition how can we apply darboux principle

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, if $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable where $I$ is a closed interval, then we assume that the one-sided derivatives exist at the boundary points of $I$. This also applies when we consider differentiable functions on half-open intervals (i.e., intervals of the form $(a,b]$ or $[a,b)$).

To answer your second question, the Darboux property for derivatives stated a bit more generally is that if $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is connected and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function, then the image of the function $f':I \to \mathbb{R}$ is connected.

So the answer is **yes**. $I$ can be a closed interval or an open interval, since those are connected.

Comment: Actually I didn't studied connectedness but little bit getting you ,sir. So it means that if we replace closed interval I=[ a,b] to open interval I=(a,b) in darbaux principle then also statement is equally true ?

Comment: @alearner Yes. You need differentiability at every point in $I$, however.

Comment: Okay sir then suppose we have problem like :- f be a real valued function such that f  is continuous in [0,2] and differentiable in (0,2) then there exists c  belongs to (0,2) such that  a) f'(c)= 1b) f'(c)= 0.4 c) f'(c) =0 d) f'(c)= 2 ? . Which of them are correct ?  Using Mean value theorem ,a is correct but what about others